# Trigger calling future method

Tags: trigger, future

I have inherited an after insert lead trigger that calls a future method. Based on the response returned by this method, it inserts records in an object. 
Lets call this object -LeadCopy__c.

```
Lead --> AFTER INSERT TRIGGER --> FUTURE METHOD --> insert records in LeadCopy__c
```

A change requested by the user is that she wants the lead record to also get updated after the future method has inserted records in that object.

1) Future method cannot return values to the calling trigger.

2) If I put another trigger on the LeadCopy__c object to update the primary lead record, it will just result in a mess.

What is the best way to make this change?

Comment: Trying to understand here, For your #2 approach, why do you think it will create an overhead if you introduce an `after insert` trigger on `LeadCopy__c` to update the associated `Lead` record?

Comment: An after insert trigger on Lead Copy to update the original lead shouldn't be an issue if done properly

Comment: Have your future update the record. In your trigger check isFuture and if true simply exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this as follows:

1. Add a new custom field on Lead: `Is_Copied__c`
2. Before calling @future, verify that `Is_Copied__c` is false
3. In @future, insert `LeadCopy__c`, update source Lead as needed and set value `Is_Copied__c = true`

Answer (score 2):

One option is to have the future method also make a record update to the Lead in addition to the LeadCopy__c insert.

Another route is with queueable methods
A @future method cannot call another @future method but it can execute a [Queueable method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm?search_text=queueable), which can be chained.

Comment: Queueable method sounds promising. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

After you process the Lead_Copy__c records you need a way to tell the `LeadTrigger` to not reprocess the leads that kicked off this cycle. To accomplish this, you'll have 2 classes and 2 triggers

- LeadTrigger
- LeadTriggerHandler
- LeadCopyTrigger
- LeadCopyTriggerHandler

On `LeadCopyTriggerHandler`, have a method called from your `LeadCopyTrigger` on the After Insert  event. This method does 3 things:

1. It iterates over the Lead_Copy__c records and gets the set of Lead Ids from the Lead_Copy__c records that were processed by this transaction.
2. It does a DML on the leads,
3. It stores these values in a `static` variable in `LeadCopyTriggerHandler` called `asyncProcessedLeads`

Then in your `LeadTriggerHandler`,if you have any logic in the update calls that you don't want applied to these leads remove any Lead Ids that are in `LeadCopyTriggerHandler.asyncProcessedLeads.`  If you don't have any update triggers on `LeadTrigger` you can disregard this last bit.

Comment: This approach appears to be a bit complicated. As of now, I don't have any triggers on the LeadCopy object. Should I introduce them or not?

Comment: Yeah, you need an after insert  on the Lead_Copy__c object to update the Lead recs.

Answer (score -1):

In Trigger Save the Data and Serialize it and pass it as a List to Future Method and decerialize it in future

Comment: I've downvoted this because I don't see how this answers the question being asked. Also, begging for upvotes is not acceptable here.